# Much difference in historic prices between brokers and others

Tags: stocks

I am analyzing e.g. TUI Group stocks.

In XTB broker we can see peak at around 20 EUR, current price ~5.2 EUR:
[image]

In Exante we can see peak at around 20 EUR, current price ~5.2 EUR:
[image]

But when we check e.g. [www.boerse-frankfurt.de](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de) (which is the stock exchange website), we can see peak at around 13 EUR, current price ~5.2 EUR:
[image]

The same goes for bloomberg or google, all of them have peak at 13 EUR and current price ~5.2 EUR:

[image]
[image]

Why the historic prices differ so greatly in brokers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them shows every single price they were traded at - and different sources have different ways to consolidate data. Maybe some take the price every minute, and others take every five minutes, so they would miss a very short spike, etc.  Also, some might show the highest and lowest for each slot; others show the average, and so on.

You would need to check each source which time resolution it uses, and how they consolidate the data within each time window.

Comment: That's really confusing, when looking on one chart you may think that the price is very undervalued, but looking at another one it tells you it's not that overvalued as you think

Answer (score 3):

The given answer is definitely not the reason that the prices are different. You cannot go from 13 to 20 just because of timing, and have completely different values throughout.  The first two charts even seem to be a standard [OHLC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart) (Open High Low Close), which means whatever period you select, it will always provide the entire range.

There can be stock splits, many stocks pay dividends, which directly affect prices and so forth. On Bloomberg, you can look at a few functions like `DPDF` to get and idea of what adjustment can be done.

On Börse Frankfurt, you have according to the website by default

> The historical prices shown here are the actual closing prices of the
> respective day without adjustment. With the selection you can decide
> whether you want to have the prices displayed corrected for corporate
> actions such as dividend markdowns, splits and/or capital increases.

Now, doing this, you can see the following for Börse Frankfurt and TUI.
[image]

A few explanations can be found [here](https://support.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=policies:adjusted_data):

> At StockCharts, we adjust our historical price data to remove gaps
> caused by stock splits, dividends and distributions. That may cause
> our charts to look different from other services that do not perform
> the same adjustments.
>
> For example, if a stock splits 2-for-1, the price is suddenly half of
> what it used to be, creating a large gap down on the chart. If you
> were unaware of the split, the chart would give you the impression
> that something bearish happened to the underlying company. In
> addition, most of the technical indicators on that chart would give
> sell signals because of the big drop in prices. Even though such a
> split is generally considered a neutral event, an unadjusted chart
> would contain lots of bearish signals.
>
> In order to prevent these kinds of misleading signals from appearing
> on our charts, we adjust all the historical data prior to the event.
> In the case of a 2-for-1 split, we divide all of the historical prices
> for the stock by 2, then multiply all of the historical volume by 2 so
> that the bars prior to the split match up smoothly with the bars that
> appear after the split.
>
> In addition to performing adjustments that remove large gaps caused by
> splits, we also adjust our historical data to remove smaller gaps
> caused by dividends and distributions. By making these additional
> adjustments, we ensure that all price movements on our charts are
> caused by pure market forces - that is, the forces that Technical
> Analysis attempts to identify.
>
> While these adjustments are very important for accurate technical
> signals, they can cause problems in the following circumstances:
>
> 1 ) Our adjusted historical price data cannot be used to determine the
> actual buy or sell price for a stock at some point in the past.
>
>  2 ) Our
> adjusted historical price data may not match up with unadjusted data
> from other sources.
>
>  3 ) Adjusting historical price data can cause P&F
> reversal points to change if “Traditional” box scaling is used (the
> default).