# Why is this stock price shown different by Google finance and other sites?

Tags: stocks

I'm looking at the stock price of Outlook Therapeutics (OLTK), and on Google Finance it is showing a meteoric rise in recent days:

https://www.google.com/finance/quote/OTLK:NASDAQ?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj59ZKGk_SEAxV93TQHHTlqA4gQ3ecFegQIJhAf&window=6M

But if you go on another site, for example marketwatch:

https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/otlk

It's actually been a gradual decline. So why is there a difference? I doubt Google would have this kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the stock had a reverse split a few days ago and Google isn't adjusting the historical data yet for that corporate action:
https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/TraderNews.aspx?id=ECA2024-122

This is a pretty common issue and it is very likely that Google simply hasn't picked up the corporate action yet. Google Finance and other free sources are also rife with these issues if you look across this substack you will see a large number of similar questions. I'm not sure why you would think than anything free would be error free.

Comment: Some more details can be found on [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154477/109107). Google is not in the business of providing financial data. It's just a free service they offer, similar to yahoo finance.

Comment: @AKdemy as always this is free as in lunch